# IF formula produces error when inserting new line

Tags: microsoft-excel, if

I am wondering if I could get some help with the below formula.
Trying to add to an original IF statement but when our team adds to it we have too many arguments error.
Any guidance is greatly appreciated, thank you!

**Original:**

```
=IFERROR(IF(Testing_Summary!G62="Correct",IF(ROUNDUP((Testing_Summary!F61/Testing_Summary!F62*100),0)>65,"Requires Significant Improvement",IF(AND(ROUNDUP((Testing_Summary!F61/Testing_Summary!F62*100),0)>37,OR(B19="Good",B19="Requires Improvement")),"Requires Improvement",IF(AND(B14="No",OR(B19="Good",B19="Requires Improvement")),"Requires Improvement",B19))),""),"")
```

**What we want to do:**

```
=IFERROR(IF(Testing_Summary!G62="Correct",IF(ROUNDUP((Testing_Summary!F61/Testing_Summary!F62*100),0)>69,"Requires Significant Improvement",IF(AND(ROUNDUP((Testing_Summary!F61/Testing_Summary!F62*100),0)>51,OR(B18="Good",B18="Satisfactory")),"Satisfactory", IF(AND(ROUNDUP((Testing_Summary!F61/Testing_Summary!F62*100),0)>37,OR(B18="Good",B18="Satisfactory",B18=”Requires Improvement”)),"Requires Improvement",IF(AND(B13="No",OR(B18="Good",B18="Satisfactory", B18=Requires Improvement”)),"Requires Improvement",B18))),""),"",””))
```

Comment: I'm guessing you've got a bracket in the wrong place resulting in `IFERROR` receiving three arguments rather than two.... or something like that.

Comment: Definitely brackets - `IFERROR(<formula>,"")`.  You have two brackets at the end of your formula - the response if an error occurs should be between them.

Comment: `B18=Requires Improvement”` in "want to do"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three sets of `,""` strings at the end of your desired formula. You must remove the first and second of them, keeping the closing parentheses after each one. Then add another closing parentheses and remove one of the final closing parentheses you have so there is only one at the end. Your formula will then look like this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(Testing_Summary!G62="Correct",IF(ROUNDUP((Testing_Summary!F61/Testing_Summary!F62*100),0)>69,"Requires Significant Improvement",IF(AND(ROUNDUP((Testing_Summary!F61/Testing_Summary!F62*100),0)>51,OR(B18="Good",B18="Satisfactory")),"Satisfactory", IF(AND(ROUNDUP((Testing_Summary!F61/Testing_Summary!F62*100),0)>37,OR(B18="Good",B18="Satisfactory",B18=”Requires Improvement”)),"Requires Improvement",IF(AND(B13="No",OR(B18="Good",B18="Satisfactory", B18=Requires Improvement”)),"Requires Improvement",B18))))),””)
```

So where you had it finishing with `B18))),""),"",””))`, it will now finish with `B18))))),””)`.

In the thought you might like to "improve" the current formula, with "improve" meaning to remove unnecessary things, you do not need to do the `ROUNDUP` work in the several `IF` tests. Please note that if using `ROUNDUP` is helpful to folks understanding the formula, what I suggest will NOT be an improvement unless the formula is somehow used tens of thousands of times in your spreadsheet. Understanding is always more important than calculation speed!

So, the logic at present is "divide the one value by the other, multiply it by 100 to get the desired digits to the left of the decimal point, then round it up to get an integer that 'gives the benefit of the doubt" so-to-speak, to compare it to a value that is a nice integer representation of a percentage." However, if you simply do the division, getting a value, perhaps 0.693665, and compare it right then to a two-digit decimal version of the comparison value, you get the same result. (Comparing the two-digit decimals so they are on the same scale, just as the multiplying by 100 achieves for comparing it to the integer version instead, and comparing to the value achieving the same thing rounding up did.)

In the above case, currently Excel would multiply the "0.693665" by 100 to get "69.3665", round it up in the "ones place" and cut it off to get "70" and finally compare it to "69" finding it is greater than it and give TRUE to the `IF`. Doing it without all that, Excel would do the division getting "0.693665", compares it to "69" finding it is greater than it and give TRUE to the `IF`. Same result but one less multiplication each time and one less function to calculate each time.

In the process you clear away quite a bit of "clutter" which might actually aid in folks understanding the formula a year from now and to be helpful for improvement in the future.

Second thing, if desiring to do that, is that Excel will allow you to use the `%` sign directly after a value to make it one-hundredth of the typed value. So typing `69%` will have Excel treat it as "0.69"... but with the very nice feature of using an easy to follow two-digit integer so no one misses seeing a leading decimal point. Since you want something .01 less than you have currently to achieve the `ROUNDUP` effect, you would type "69%", "51%", and "37%" but Excel would see them as two-digit decimals. Good for you and good for Excel.

If you'd like to do that, the following will work:

```
=IFERROR(IF(Testing_Summary!G62="Correct",IF(Testing_Summary!F61/Testing_Summary!F62>69%,"RequiresSignificantImprovement",IF(AND(Testing_Summary!F61/Testing_Summary!F62>51%,OR(B18="Good",B18="Satisfactory")),"Satisfactory",IF(AND(Testing_Summary!F61/Testing_Summary!F62>37%,OR(B18="Good",B18="Satisfactory",B18=”RequiresImprovement”)),"RequiresImprovement",IF(AND(B13="No",OR(B18="Good",B18="Satisfactory",B18=RequiresImprovement”)),"RequiresImprovement",B18))))),"")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This is very helpful in understanding more about this formula  and how it can be cleaned up. Again thank you, I will be going with your suggestion of decluttering so others can understand.